# Instagram Api authorization in background

Tags: json, api, authorization, instagram

I´m connecting my web application to my Instagram app in order to show the last 100 comments/post of an specific hashtag.

I have the clientId, clientSecret, the website and the redirect url.

The Instagram Api documentation refer to call the authorization url before the access token call.

The authorization url is neccesary to get the code for request the access token.

Is the any way to get that code in background, using Ajax, or Post with Json, for instance.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the url `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{hashtag}/media/recent?client_id={clientId}&count={count}` I can request the Instagram Api without authorization process.

Thanks